# SQL Developer Query to Output data in one table not in another

Tags: sql

Have the following example data:

`Shipment table
    Shipment_ID Readable_Shipment_ID
    12345       ICanReadThis

    Shipment_Detail table
    Shpmnt_ID   Shpmnt_Dtl_ID   PO_ID   PO_Dtl_ID1  Product_ID
    12345       10000           11111    100        10203045
    12345       10001           11111    110        10204589
    12345       10002           11111    120        10205896
    12345       10003           11111    130        10211212
    12345       10004           11111    140        10305566`

```
Purchase_Order_Detail table
PO_ID   PO_Dtl_ID2  Product_ID2
11111    1          10203045
11111    2          10204589
11111    5          10305566
```

I am trying to craft a query that returns a list of Product_ID values that exist in the Shipment_Detail table but are absent in the Purchase_Order_Detail table.

Complicating things is that I would like to use the Human Readable Shipment number (Readable_Shipment_ID) as the input, since that is what is given to me as a starting point.

I have come up with this, and it works, but requires either a bind variable or hard-coding in the Readable_Shipment_ID value:

```
<code>
select table_a.shipment,
    table_a.purchase_order,
    table_a.shp_dtl_line
    table_a.item,
    table_b.*
from (select shp.readable_shipment_id Shipment, 
    shp_dtl.po_id Purchase_Order,
    shp_dtl.shpmnt_dtl_id Shp_Dtl_Line,
    shp_dtl.product_id Item
    from shipment shp, shipment_detail shp_dtl
    where shp_dtl.shpmnt_id = shp.shpmnt_id) table_a
LEFT JOIN (select pod.po_id po_id,
    pod.po_dtl_id2 po_line_id,
    pod.product_id2 PO_Article
    from purchase_orders_detail pod
    where pod.po_id in ( select distinct shp_dtl.po_id
        from shp_dtl shp_dtl, shipment shp
        where shp_dtl.shpmnt_id = shp.shpmnt_id
        and shp.readable_shipment_id = :MySHP )
    ) table_b
ON table_b.po_article = table_a.item
where table_b.po_article IS NULL
and table_a.shipment = :MySHP;
</code>
```

Forgive any syntax errors, I am still fairly new to the SQL language. The fields in the query were changed to anonymize the query.

I am looking for a way to avoid the bind variable ':MySHP' and am certain there must be a way to refactor this query with a different join or method I can't see, or don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after?

```
Select Distinct SD.Product_ID
From 
    Shipment_Detail SD 
    join Shipment S on S.Shipment_ID = SD.Shpmnt_ID
    left join Purchase_Order_Detail POD on POD.Product_ID2 = SD.Product_ID
Where
    S.Readable_Shipment_ID = @YourParameter
    and POD.Product_ID2 IS NULL
```

It will only return the Product_ID from Shipment_Detail if it doesn't exist in Purchase_Order_Detail, and will only return Product_IDs related to the Readable_Shipment_ID value that you specify

Comment: Thank you for response. I need to clarify. The POD.Product_ID2 is not unique. The same product ID can exist across many different purchase orders and shipments. The logic of what I believe needs to happen is to search for all the records in the shipment_detail table and return the Product_ID list. Then the left join seeks to find the list of purchase_order_detail records and return that list of Product_IDs. Then compare the two. Since the Product_ID can repeat in both the shipment_detail AND purchase_order_detail, the left join on product_ID returns no records (expected I think).